# Iterating through SQL Tables in python

Tags: python, sql

Currently, my code is something like this.

```
best_Data = 
[[1,2,3,4,5,6],
 [10,11,12,13,14,15],
 [20,21,22,23,24,25]]
```

This value updates regularly and I currently capture it every 15 minutes and store it in three separate worksheets, each of which contains one of the sublists, which update every 15 minutes as the data updates. For example, `wb1` would be updated with `[1,2,3,4,5,6]`, while `wb2` would get `[10,11,12,13,14,15]` and so on.

This i s the code I currently use to do this:

```
for sheet in wb:        
        sheet.append(best_Data[m])
        m = m + 1
wb.save('Data.xlsx')
```

However, the worksheets are quickly running out of space and I'm thinking of switching to `SQLite`. Is there any way to replicate the above piece of code by iterating through tables in `SQLite` or would I have to brute force it?

The brute force method would look something like this.

```
c.execute("INSERT INTO Tbl1 VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)", best_Data[1])
c.execute("INSERT INTO Tbl2 VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)", best_Data[2])
c.execute("INSERT INTO Tbl3 VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)", best_Data[3])
```

The other problem with this is that sometimes the data isn't uniform ie a meter breaks down and returns an error. Is `SQLite` flexible enough for this brute force method?

Comment: First time asking a question, is this the right format for everything/does the question make sense?

Comment: More detail is needed about your data, most particularly about what the different rows mean.  It's likely that a single database table would be most appropriate, with an additional column containing an identifier that distinguishes between the rows corresponding to best_Data[1], best_Data[2], and best_Data[3].

Comment: Let me clarify: can you define your `best_data` not as list of list but like 3 independent variables `best_data_1`, `best_data_2`, `best_data_3`?  And your update process can be divided into 3 **independent** processes?

Comment: Indeed, if you have a time dependent update, why not even consider making the inserts row unique by utilizing the timestamp as the identifier.

Comment: Ah sorry about that. The data is solar data and there are 34 inverters that I'm currently sending to 34 different worksheets. The data is 3-dimensional(time x inverter x power measurement) so I'd rather have then in 34 different table rather than one huge data table because it would be easier to visualize/analyze


@lngaz I can probably do something like best_data1 = best_data[1] etc... but I don't see why that would help because I would still have to brute force the SQL side.

Comment: To be more specific, the rows would be time, the columns would be (INV 1 Leg 1 Power, INV 1 Leg 1 Efficiency, INV 1 Leg 2 Power,...INV 1 Leg 6 Efficiency) and the tables would be INV 1- 34.